# FormName has no attribute 'error_messages'

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-views

I am asking You to help me get over that error:
`'NewAnnouncementForm' has no attribute 'error_messages'`

So, I have a "Announcement" model:

```
class Announcement(models.Model):

    announcement = 'announcement'
    alert = 'alert'
    offer ='offer'

    announcement_types = (
    (announcement, 'Announcement'),
    (alert, 'Alert'),
    (offer, 'Offer'),
    )

    id = models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=True, verbose_name='ID')
    text = models.CharField(max_length=1500, null=False, blank=False)
    announcement_type = models.CharField(max_length=12, choices=announcement_types, default=announcement)
    user_name = models.ForeignKey(CustomUserModel, db_column='user_name', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    building_id = models.ForeignKey(Buildings, db_column='building_id', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

And I am trying to make a form and view to allow user add his announcements. Here is my form:

```
class NewAnnouncementForm(forms.ModelForm):

    text = forms.CharField(label='Treść ogłoszenia', max_length=1500)
    announcement_type = forms.ChoiceField(label='Typ ogłoszenia', widget=forms.RadioSelect, choices=Announcement.announcement_types)
    #user_name dodac do views przed savem i dodac w save (?)
    price = forms.DecimalField(label='Podaj oczekiwaną cenę, w przypadku darmowego ogłoszenia wpisz 0')
    user_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())
    building_id = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())

    class Meta(forms.Form):
        model = Announcement
        fields = ('text', 'announcement_type', 'price', 'user_name', 'building_id')

    def save(self, commit=True):
        announcement = super(NewAnnouncementForm, self).save(commit=False)
        announcement.text = self.cleaned_data['text']
        announcement.announcement_type = self.cleaned_data['announcement_type']
        announcement.price = self.cleaned_data['price']

        if commit:
            announcement.save()
        return announcement
```

And views.py which is a main problem i guess:

```
def add_announcement(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        if request.method=='POST':
            username = str(request.user.username)
            user_object = CustomUserModel.objects.values_list('address', flat=True).get(username=username)
            form = NewAnnouncementForm(request.POST)
            form.fields['user_name'].initial = username
            form.fields['building_id'].initial = user_object
            if form.is_valid():
                announcement = form.save()
                messages.success(request, 'Dodano ogłoszenie')
                return redirect("map_neigh:index")
            else:
                for msg in form.error_messages:
                    messages.error(request, str(msg) + ": " + str(form.error_messages[msg]))

                return render(request = request,
                              template_name = "map_neigh/add.html",
                              context={"form":form})

        form = NewAnnouncementForm
        return render(request = request,
                      template_name = "map_neigh/add.html",
                      context={"form":form})
```

The problem I am facing since few hours is that after trying to submit form, I get error: `'NewAnnouncementForm' has no attribute 'error_messages'` Same error messages script works well for registration and it's form so I don't think it's connected to imports.

Comment: Normally a form has `.errors`, not `.error_messages`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use `.error_messages`. This is something that is a dictionary to show the *possible* error messages for a certain field. A form has a [**`.errors`** attribute [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.errors) that specifies the errors:

```
for field, items in form.errors.items():
    for item in items:
        messages.error(request, '{}: {}'.format(field, item))
```

Comment: Now I get it, thank you very much!

However this loop returned me an django error about too many values to unpack, but changing it to 
```
                for field in form.errors:
                    for item in form.errors:
                        messages.error(request, '{}: {}'.format(field,item))
```
worked well.